# how to indent results of mysql SELECT INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, indentation, file-io

I have an sql table that I want to dump to an outfile. The thing is, some of the results are 1 digit, i.e 1 or 2, while others are long numbers, i.e. `1.2323523`

This causes the outfile to look terrible, something like this

```
1   a bbb
1.21321342 aaaa bbbbb
```

meaning, the beginning of each column is not aligned. Does anyone know if there is a way in sql to take care of that?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cast the columns as char(n), eg

```
select cast(my_numeric_column as char(10)) as my_numeric_column
```

This will be output fixed-width column data. They will however be left justified.

A better solution would be to give the same number of decimal places to all numbers, 1 would be output as "1.000000" etc. This is how to do that:

```
select cast(my_numeric_column as decimal(16,8)) as my_numeric_column
```

Chose the precision (number of places - here 8) you want.

All columns can be treated in this way to produce a nicely tabulated format.

Comment: is there a way to get this to work for the entire table, and not just 1 row each time?

Answer (score 1):

use like this u get a csv file, so in excel its look pretty

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/table.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the [string manipulation functions in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html). Notably, [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) or [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format).